# Is this the right way to implement oAuth 2.0 for azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-appservice, azure-oauth

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrBqNYtyj8 video to secure my backend API using Azure API management. After following the steps the workflow was not working and I had to add an additional step. After adding the step, I got oAuth workflow working.

**But I wonder if this is the right way to implement oAuth workflow?** As per [this article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/protect-api-s-using-oauth-2-0-in-apim/ba-p/2309538?lightbox-message-images-2309538=276637iDD232FC09F45D825), **I am suppose to add inbound policy which I have not implemented. Please provide suggestions**

**I followed following steps**:

1. Using Azure AD add backend application.

   [image]
2. Go to Manifest and update `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to 2 and save.
   Set the `appId URI` for backend app & `add scope`

   [image]
3. Enable authentication for backend API. In the `Redirect URI's` textbox, after backend api url add `/.auth/login/aad/callback`

   [image]
4. Now go to back to `app service` (assuming App service is hosting your backend api) > `Authentication > Add an identity provider` > from next window select `Microsoft as identity provider` and select Pick an `existing app registration` in this directory radio button from app registration type. Keep remaining settings as default and click add.

   [image]
5. At this point of time your backend api is secure.
6. Register client app

   [image]
7. Grant Permission. After granting permission, Click on Manifest and change value of `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to `2`

   [image]
8. Now select `api permission` > Click + `add permission` > select `My API’s` tab > select the backend app we created and select scope & click `Add permissions`.

   [image]
9. Create Client Certificate: Under client app, select `Certificates & Secrets` > Click on + `New Client Secret` > provide a some description & click Add.

**Following are additional steps I added which was not available in video:**

1. Under client app > Overview > Endpoints > Make note of token and authorize endpoints:

   [image]
2. Open `API Management > select OAuth 2.0 + OpenID connect > + Add` button

   [image]

   [image]
3. Now open APIM > APIs > Select your API > Settings > Under Security > User Authorization select oAuth2.0 radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that, inbound policy is used to check whether the Access token is valid or not. It checks the value of the access token in the **`aud`** claim.

You can add the **inbound policy** based on your requirement like below:

*Go to APIM -> APIs -> Select you API -> All Operations -> Select Inbound processing*

[image]

You can try the below sample Policy and **Save**:

```json
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/aadtenant/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="aud">
            <value>backendappclient-id</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

[image]

The steps who have followed to **implement oAuth workflow** is accurate and will secure backend API using Azure API management successfully.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Authorize test console of API Management developer portal using OAuth 2.0 user authorization - Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2)